# My custom cell gets messed up after being clicked?

Tags: iphone, uiview, label, tableview, cell

Before: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2j6a4h4&s=6
After:  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=demxi&s=6

I have a problem with my cell's layout in the listView after being clicked. As you can see in the before and after pictures, the 3 labels in my cells (name, book, chapter) gets all messed up? What have I missed in my code? /Regards

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BookmarkCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
Bookmark *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSArray *chunks = [item.name componentsSeparatedByString: @","];

NSString *name;
NSString *book;
NSString *chapter;

if ([chunks count] > 0)
{
    name = [chunks objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([chunks count] > 1)
    {
        book = [chunks objectAtIndex:1];
        if ([chunks count] > 2)
        {
            chapter = [chunks objectAtIndex:2];
        }
    }
}

UIView * pNewContentView= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
CGRect labelFrame= pNewContentView.bounds;
labelFrame.size.height= labelFrame.size.height * 0.5;

UILabel* pLabel1=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
[pNewContentView addSubview:pLabel1];

labelFrame.origin.y= labelFrame.size.height;
UILabel* pLabel2=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
[pNewContentView addSubview:pLabel2];

labelFrame.origin.y= labelFrame.origin.y + labelFrame.size.height;
UILabel* pLabel3=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
[pNewContentView addSubview:pLabel3];

[cell.contentView addSubview:pNewContentView];

[pLabel1 setText:(name)];    
[pLabel2 setText:(book)];  
[pLabel3 setText:(chapter)];       




return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return 70; // height of tableView Cell
}
```

Comment: I think it is because you're adding pNewContentView to the cell multiple things in case of dequeued cells. You'll want to move that whole block of code into the "if (cell == nil)" statement.

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding on what @onnoweb said and moving it to answer section as he's right:

What is happening is for every cell refresh, you are adding additional 3 labels to each cell causing a real bad memory hog. The paint issue is caused by new labels obscuring the old cause all labels have white BG by default.

You want to move the label creation code to where you initialize the newly created cell, but there is an issue with that where there is no elegant way to access added labels in already existing cells. My suggestion is for customized cells, such as this one, always create a customized subclass of UITableViewCell. (I personally think it's the most elegant approach):

for ex:
UIMyCustomTableViewCell.h

```
@interface UIMyCustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label3;

@end
```

UIMyCustomTableViewCell.m

```
@implementation UIMyCustomTableViewCell
@synthesize label1 = _label1;
@synthesize label1 = _label2;
@synthesize label1 = _label3;

... init, memory cleanup, etc.

@end
```

At that point you can use that cell in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code:

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UIMyCustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    CGRect labelFrame = cell.bounds;
    labelFrame.size.height= labelFrame.size.height * 0.5;

    cell.label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
    etc...
}

cell.label1.text = ...
cell.label2.text = ...
cell.label3.text = ...
```

I'm also a big fan of setting up look and feel of all customized cells in xib files instead of initializing labels in code like above, much cleaner in sizable apps.

Hope this helps.